# How to write http interceptor in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Since I have already worked on backbone and now I am learning angular. I really liked the way angular gives features. I was just thinking about how can we implement the HTTP interceptor in backbone in order to show spinner and toaster while your JavaScript saves or fetches data to/from back-end using AJAX. And eventually I found a way to do it. Thought of sharing it. Hope it helps you all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using requireJS if not just convert the AMD to IIFE

```
define("vent", ["backbone", "backbone.marionette"], function(backbone) {
    return new backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator
});
define("backbone-sync", ["backbone", "underscore", "vent"], function(backbone, underscore, vent) {
    var xhrArray = [];
    var abortAllPendingXhrs = function() {
        underscore.invoke(xhrArray, "abort"),
        xhrArray = []
    };
    // here options can contain the text which you want to show on spinner and toaster
    var showSpinnerandToaster = function(method, options) {
        if("create" === method || "update" === method || "patch" === method) {
            //show saving spinner
        }
        if("read" === method) {
            //show fetching spinner
        }
        //using once here because none of this will be called twice
        //'sync' event is fired on the model/collection when ajax gets succeeded
        this.once("sync", function() {
            //hide the spinner and show success toaster
            //remove cancelRequest since now on you can not abort the AJAX
            delete this.cancelRequest;
            //remove error callback since it will not be called now
            this.off("error");
        });
        //'error' event is fired on the model/collection when ajax fails
        this.once("error", function(model, xhr) {
            //show error toaster if the xhr.statusText !== "abort"
            //remove cancelRequest since now on you can not abort the AJAX
            delete this.cancelRequest;
            //remove sync callback since it will not be called now
            this.off("sync");
        });
    };
    vent.on("abortAllPendingXhrs", abortAllPendingXhrs);
    backbone.Model.prototype.sync = backbone.Collection.prototype.sync = function(method, model, options) {
        var proxiedShowSpinnerandToaster = underscore.bind(showSpinnerandToaster, this);
        proxiedShowSpinnerandToaster(method, options)
        var xhr = backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
        xhrArray.push(xhr);
        xhrArray = underscore.reject(xhrArray, function(xhr) {
            //remove all xhrs which are completed since we can not abort them
            return 4 === xhr.readyState
        }),
        this.cancelRequest = function(){
            //invoke cancelRequest on model if you want to abort the AJAX call
            xhr.abort();
        }
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Apart from posting this here, I guess it would good to update the SO documentation for BackboneJS here - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/backbone.js/topics

Comment: @ DavidR sure i Will do so.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil! :-)